# HTML input with nested img layout bug on IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'am having problems with IE8 and my html/css =/

The code works fine in Chrome, IE9, Mozilla and Safari.
But on IE8 it is ugly:

[image]

I've tried a lot of things but no results. It seams to be a problem with the padding...

HTML:

```
<div class="TituloDasTelas">
<span id="MainContent_LabelTituloTela">Test</span>
<span style="font-size: x-large">|</span>
<div class="buttons">

<input name="ctl00$MainContent$TextBoxFiltro" type="text" maxlength="100" id="MainContent_TextBoxFiltro" title="" class="TextBox300">

<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ButtonPesquisar" value="Pesquisar" id="MainContent_ButtonPesquisar" class="regular">

<input type="button" id="PesqAvancada" value="" class="ButtonPesqAvancada" title="">

<img id="MainContent_ImagePesquisaAvancada" class="imgPesqAvancada" src="../../Include/Imagens/down.gif" alt="Pesq.Avançada">


<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$ButtonExportarParaExcel" value="Exportar" id="MainContent_ButtonExportarParaExcel" title="" class="positive">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.buttons
{
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
 .buttons input[type=submit], .buttons input[type=button]
{
    border-right: 1px solid #dedede;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    display: inline;
    float: center;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande" , Tahoma, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 130%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #565656;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.buttons input[type=submit], .buttons input[type=button]
{
    width: 150px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 4px 10px 3px 7px;
}

.buttons button[type]
{
    line-height: 17px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 7px;
}
:first-child + html button[type]
{
    padding: 4px 10px 3px 7px;
}
.buttons button img, .buttons a img
{
    border: none;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 0 3px -3px 0 !important;
    padding: 0;
}
input[type=submit].positive, .buttons a.positive
{
    color: #529214;
}
.buttons a.positive:hover, input[type=submit].positive:hover, .buttons input[type=button]:hover
{
    background-color: #E6EFC2;
    border: 1px solid #C6D880;
    color: #529214;
}
.buttons a.positive:active
{
    background-color: #529214;
    border: 1px solid #529214;
    color: #fff;
}
.buttons a.negative, input[type=submit].negative, .buttons input[type=button]
{
    color: #d12f19;
}
.buttons a.negative:hover, input[type=submit].negative:hover, .buttons input[type=button]:hover
{
    background: #fbe3e4;
    border: 1px solid #fbc2c4;
    color: #d12f19;
}
.buttons a.negative:active
{
    background-color: #d12f19;
    border: 1px solid #d12f19;
    color: #fff;
}
input[type=submit].regular, .buttons a.regular, .buttons input[type=button]
{
    color: #369;
}
input[type=submit]:hover, .buttons a:hover, .buttons a.regular:hover, input[type=submit].regular:hover, .buttons input[type=button]:hover
{
    background-color: #dff4ff;
    border: 1px solid #c2e1ef;
    color: #369;
}
.buttons a:active, .buttons a.regular:active
{
    background-color: #6299c5;
    border: 1px solid #6299c5;
    color: #fff;
}

.ButtonPesqAvancada, .buttons input[type=button]
{
    width: 6px;
    margin-left: -6px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.imgPesqAvancada 
{
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-left:-20px;
    z-index: -1px;
}
```

Serious I don't know what is the problem.
Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please clean up your CSS before pasting. It is difficult to read.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> as doctype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the problem.
It has to do with de font of the input.
I wrote "1" o the input value and made it the same color of the background. Now it seams fine on all browser.